# Roles not working on controller. .NET Core API

Tags: api, .net-core, authorization, roles

I'm trying to authorize a method of my AuthController, I have implemented it this way:

**AuthController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost("register")]
    [Authorize]
    [EnableCors("AllowAllHeaders")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        // bla bla bla
    }
```

the method without the [Authorize] actually works. on my Startup.cs i have the following config

**Startup.cs**

```
IdentityBuilder builder = services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        });

        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
        builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>();
        builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                        .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
        {
            opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Configure method

```
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

Is there some config still missing ?

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to authorize with Roles = "Admin" in order to register an account, but I don't have any other response than 401.

this is a token generated on my login method, which I use on Authorization header:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxMSIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoiQXpyYWVsIiwicm9sZSI6WyJBZG1pbiIsIkVtcGxveWVlIl0sIm5iZiI6MTU4NTQzNzgzNywiZXhwIjoxNTg1NTI0MjM3LCJpYXQiOjE1ODU0Mzc4Mzd9.DwDCeMXBrgzGeI1w2PgnIlYeccma73BaFuN2p1ryzlwCJr815V6Q3hYMzX-PXfmOr_94fQnM4PHbJPwRNoTItw

Comment: Is the order of UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() is the problem?

Comment: Yes indeed. thank you very much ! If you write an answer, I'll mark it as it was the solution for my problem.

Comment: Glad to help. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() isn't right in the Configure method. Authentication should be first and then Authorization:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```